# webworksready function not fireing

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry-webworks

I have just a simple web works page but my code is not firing.  The load function alert fires but not the `webworksready` function.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.   I thought it may be an issue with the js, so I pointed directly to the webworks.js file itself.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bbui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bbui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webworks.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        alert("load function");
        document.addEventListener("webworksready", function(){
            alert("Im in web works ready function");
        });
    }, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which SDK are you using? The code you've pasted is for WebWorks v1, and it looks correct to me. If so, are you testing on a device/simulator or in the browser? This event shouldn't fire if you're just testing in Chrome.

If you're using the new WebWorks 2 (powered by Cordova), things have changed a little bit. You'll do something like this instead...

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- cordova -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- initialization -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    Application.initialize();
</script>

<!-- cordova code, usually in another file, not inline, but either way... -->
<script>


var Application = {

    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        blackberry.event.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        Application.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        // this is now, essentially your webworks ready function.

    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

</script>
```